# Structure of the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which sentence is correct and if both are correct , please tell me how to use them properly

1- If you wanted to come , let me know
2- If you want to come , let me know

Answer (score 1):

> If you wanted to come, let me know.

This sentence is incorrect as it stands. To correct it, you could change it into a question. For example,

> If you had wanted to come, then why didn't you let me know?

In other words, the focus is on the past and what should have been done, but wasn't.

The sentence

> If you want to come, let me know

is correct as it stands, if the event (let's say) is in the future and the person coming is unsure if he *will* come. If he does decide to come, then he is to let you know.

The question I ask you now is, Which situation pertains? Are you looking back or looking forward (i.e., past or future)?

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct,
let's start with the  second sentence:

```
If you want to come , let me know
```

In this case you are trying to ask someone in the present if he could come in the near futur.

In the second case which is the first sentence:

```
If you wanted to come , let me know
```

The action of asking someone to come is finished but you are telling him that you asked him in the passed that if he want to come he should let you know.